# Removing extra page before and after \tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking

My main file generate extra page before `\tableofcontents` with header title "Table of contents". How can I remove this page?  I am copying the `main.tex` file code for your reference.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{Classes/aesm_edspia}

\begin{document}
\addtocounter{page}{-1}
\makethese 
\onehalfspacing
\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}\addtocounter{page}{-5}


%depth in the table of contents and section numbering
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\frontmatter

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Acknowledgements}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Table of Contents}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\input{Abstract/Abstract}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables 

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Introduction}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: you are using the `twoside` option. As such, this is the expected behavior, since all chapter pages should start on an `odd` page.

Comment: Thanks Mario for your answer. However, I would like to add something  more in my question:  I am getting an extra blank page with header title "Table of contents" . How can I remove this page?

Comment: That's because of your command `\tableofcontents`, which lists all the chapters/sections of your document.  If you wish to remove it, simple comment it out or completely delete it.  However, the table of contents is widely used in many reports/books, so I would make sure it is not required as part of your work before removing it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

that is the default for a twosided document. However, you can use:

```
...
\begingroup
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\endgroup
...
```

then it starts on the following page.