# Deleting extra page when using ToC

Tags: table-of-contents

How can I delete the extra page created when using table of contents?

The page shows the name of the table of contents and the rest is empty.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139289/removing-extra-page-before-and-after-tableofcontents?s=3|2.0321

Comment: For such questions, we always need to see an MWE. We can not guess what document settings and such which behaviour you have for your file. I marked it as a duplicate as this question has many answers on this site. If you think, your issue is special, show it to us!