# Abstract right next to the table of contents in documentclass book

Tags: abstract

I am writing my thesis in Latex, using texmaker but i have too many white pages that i want to get rid of but don't know how. Maybe someone here has an idea:) Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

    \include{...}

\end{titlepage}

\include{./chapters/statutory_declaration}

\clearpage

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\frontmatter

\include{./chapters/abstract} %% without this everything is exactly as I wish.. but I'd like to include the abstract on the left page right next to the table of contents... if I include it like this there is another blank page between the statutory_declaration and the abstract and between abstract and table of contents....

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{page}{0}

\mainmatter

\include{./chapters/introduction}

\include{./chapters/chapter_01}

\include{./chapters/chapter_02}

\include{./chapters/chapter_03}

\include{./chapters/conclusion}

%% Bibliography

\bibliographystyle{alpha}

\bibliography{...}

\end{document}
```

If someone could help me I would be really thankful!!! Since this is my very first MWE just let me know if I missed something important for you to know. 
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  This is not really an MWE as it refers to many files we do not have.  Relpacing the `\include...` statements by `\chapter{...}text` probably produces something close to what you are seeing.  Perhaps https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139289/15925 could help with solving your actual problem.

Comment: The simplest could be `\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}` or use the answer of Adrew for only some parts, but if the reason is save paper, btw you could also `\renewcommand{\clearpage}{}` ... However, do you want to present some kind of brochure or a formal  thesis? For the second is always a bad idea do not allow blank pages avoiding start chapters only in even pages.

Comment: Thanks Andrew your answer worked just fine for me! You're right I should have replaced the \include by a blindtext!

Answer (score 1):

The technique of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139334/15925 can be applied as follows, removing removing 4 blank pages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
Title
\end{titlepage}

\begingroup
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage

\chapter*{Declaration}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\frontmatter

\chapter*{Abstract}

\tableofcontents

\endgroup

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{First chapter}

\end{document}
```